# Apache POI Cellstyle doesnt apply after 41st row for some reason

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

As you can understand from the title, after 41st row, my style doesnt apply even though with debugging i saw that code is working well.

My Function is:

```
private void writeTable(Table table,Row row,Workbook wb){
    CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
    if(row.getRowNum() % 2 == 0) {

        cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_TURQUOISE.getIndex());
        cellStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        cellStyle.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cellStyle.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        cellStyle.setWrapText(true);
        cellStyle.setTopBorderColor(IndexedColors.GREY_80_PERCENT.getIndex());
        cellStyle.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        cellStyle.setBottomBorderColor(IndexedColors.GREY_80_PERCENT.getIndex());
        cellStyle.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        cellStyle.setRightBorderColor(IndexedColors.GREY_80_PERCENT.getIndex());
        cellStyle.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        cellStyle.setLeftBorderColor(IndexedColors.GREY_80_PERCENT.getIndex());
    }else{

        cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex());
        cellStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        cellStyle.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cellStyle.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        cellStyle.setWrapText(true);
        cellStyle.setTopBorderColor(IndexedColors.GREY_80_PERCENT.getIndex());
        cellStyle.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        cellStyle.setBottomBorderColor(IndexedColors.GREY_80_PERCENT.getIndex());
        cellStyle.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        cellStyle.setRightBorderColor(IndexedColors.GREY_80_PERCENT.getIndex());
        cellStyle.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        cellStyle.setLeftBorderColor(IndexedColors.GREY_80_PERCENT.getIndex());
    }

    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue(Table.index);
    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);


    cell = row.createCell(1);
    cell.setCellValue(strCorrecter(Table.Name).isEmpty() ? "-" : strCorrecter(Table.Name));
    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

    cell = row.createCell(2);
    cell.setCellValue(strCorrecter(Table.Surname.toString()).isEmpty() ? "-" : strCorrecter(Table.Surname.toString()));
    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

    cell = row.createCell(3);
    cell.setCellValue("TODO");
    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

    cell = row.createCell(4);
    cell.setCellValue(strCorrecter(Table.Age.toString()).isEmpty() ? "-" : strCorrecter(Table.Age.toString()));
    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

    cell = row.createCell(5);
    cell.setCellValue("TODO");
    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

    cell =row.createCell(6);
    cell.setCellValue("TODO");
    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

    cell = row.createCell(7);
    cell.setCellValue("TODO");
    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

    cell = row.createCell(8);
    cell.setCellValue("TODO");
    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

    cell = row.createCell(9);
    cell.setCellValue("TODO");
    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

    cell = row.createCell(10);
    cell.setCellValue("TODO");
    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

    cell = row.createCell(11);
    cell.setCellValue("TODO");
    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

    cell = row.createCell(12);
    cell.setCellValue("TODO");
    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

    cell = row.createCell(13);
    cell.setCellValue("TODO");
    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

    cell = row.createCell(14);
    cell.setCellValue("TODO");
    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
}
```

And i see that all rows go through if else statement in the beginning of the function. But they dont seem to have any attributes when i look at the excel file. And this is the part where i call this function:

```
 int rowCount = 3;
 for (Table table : tableList){
        Row row = sheet.createRow(++rowCount);
        writeInterlock(table,row,workbook);
    }
```

I've no idea whats happening so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: There is an [Excel limit](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) for the maximum number of unique cell formats/cell styles in a workbook. So **don't** create a cell style for each single row. As far as I see, you only needs **two** different cell styles. So create those two as `cellStyle1` and `cellStyle2` outside the method and only use one of the two inside the method.

Comment: How can go beyond that excel limit? And for some reason i created 2 styles and now it ends in 16th row:D

Comment: You can't go beyond that excel limit. And you should creating the two cell styles **outside** the method you have provided. But a really good answer is not possible since you are not providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It worked thank god I love you mate:D if you post this comment as an answer I'd gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [Excel limit](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) for the maximum number of unique cell formats/cell styles in a workbook.

So **don't** create a cell style for each single row. As far as I see, you only needs two different cell styles. So create those two as `cellStyle1` and `cellStyle2` **outside** the method:

```
...
CellStyle cellStyle1 = wb.createCellStyle();
//set all the needed settings
CellStyle cellStyle2 = wb.createCellStyle();
//set all the needed settings
...
```

and then only **use** the two within the method:

```
private void writeTable(Table table,Row row,Workbook wb) {
 ...
 if(row.getRowNum() % 2 == 0) {
  //here use cellStyle1
 } else {
  //here use cellStyle2
 }
 ...
}
```

Comment: Anyway you are doing this in a static way

Answer (score 0):

The answer you accpeted isnt totally correct , there is a limit, ok , but the peoblem happen to you its because you are using an implementation of excel 97'(-2007) , here there is a [link](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/) .

If you don't really need a file in **.xls** format , below a working example (similar to yours) which doesn't need manage variable in a **static way** as you do in the answer you accepted.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class MainWriteCells {

    public MainWriteCells() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\ook.xlsx"));
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");

        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
            writeTable(sheet.createRow(i),wb);
        }
        wb.write(new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\ook.xlsx")));

    }

    private static void writeTable(Row row,Workbook wb){
        CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
        if(row.getRowNum() % 2 == 0) {

            cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_TURQUOISE.getIndex());
            cellStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            cellStyle.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cellStyle.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
            cellStyle.setWrapText(true);
            cellStyle.setTopBorderColor(IndexedColors.GREY_80_PERCENT.getIndex());
            cellStyle.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
            cellStyle.setBottomBorderColor(IndexedColors.GREY_80_PERCENT.getIndex());
            cellStyle.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
            cellStyle.setRightBorderColor(IndexedColors.GREY_80_PERCENT.getIndex());
            cellStyle.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
            cellStyle.setLeftBorderColor(IndexedColors.GREY_80_PERCENT.getIndex());
        }else{

            cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex());
            cellStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            cellStyle.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cellStyle.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
            cellStyle.setWrapText(true);
            cellStyle.setTopBorderColor(IndexedColors.GREY_80_PERCENT.getIndex());
            cellStyle.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
            cellStyle.setBottomBorderColor(IndexedColors.GREY_80_PERCENT.getIndex());
            cellStyle.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
            cellStyle.setRightBorderColor(IndexedColors.GREY_80_PERCENT.getIndex());
            cellStyle.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
            cellStyle.setLeftBorderColor(IndexedColors.GREY_80_PERCENT.getIndex());
        }

        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue("TODO");
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);


        cell = row.createCell(1);
        cell.setCellValue("TODO");
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

        cell = row.createCell(2);
        cell.setCellValue("TODO");
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

        cell = row.createCell(3);
        cell.setCellValue("TODO");
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

        cell = row.createCell(4);
        cell.setCellValue("TODO");
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

        cell = row.createCell(5);
        cell.setCellValue("TODO");
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

        cell =row.createCell(6);
        cell.setCellValue("TODO");
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

        cell = row.createCell(7);
        cell.setCellValue("TODO");
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

        cell = row.createCell(8);
        cell.setCellValue("TODO");
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

        cell = row.createCell(9);
        cell.setCellValue("TODO");
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

        cell = row.createCell(10);
        cell.setCellValue("TODO");
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

        cell = row.createCell(11);
        cell.setCellValue("TODO");
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

        cell = row.createCell(12);
        cell.setCellValue("TODO");
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

        cell = row.createCell(13);
        cell.setCellValue("TODO");
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

        cell = row.createCell(14);
        cell.setCellValue("TODO");
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
    }

}
```

As you can see i changed two objects and the file extension in **.xslx**

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
```

Instead of

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(is);
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
```